# AngularJS filter does not sync the input value from module

Tags: angularjs, filter

Hello I am new to AngularJS and met a question. I need to create a customized filter to filter a string, however the filter cannot sync the input result. Because **the filter.js has to be made into a separated JS file**, I thought I have to import $scope.delimiter from controller.js to filter.js, but I don't know how to do it. Thank you very much in advanced.
HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Tokenizer Filter</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <script src="filter.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TokenizeControler">
        <p>Input: <input ng-model="greeting" /></p>
        <p>Delimiter: <input id="delimiter"  ng-model="delimiter" /></p>
        <p>{{delimiter}}</p>
        <p>{{greeting | tokenize: defualt}}</p>
        <p>{{greeting | tokenize}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller.js:

```
var myApp = angular
    .module("myApp", [])
    .controller("TokenizeControler",
        function ($scope) {
            $scope.greeting = "Angular is awesome";
            $scope.delimiter = "#";
            $scope.defualt = true;

    });
```

filter.js:

```
myApp.filter("tokenize", function () {
    return function (content, defualt) {
            if (angular.isString(content)) {
                var noSpace, output;
                noSpace = content.replace(/ +/g, "");
                if (defualt) {
                    return output = noSpace.split('').join(',') + " (Default)";
                } else {
                    delimiter =  document.getElementById('delimiter').value;

                    return output = noSpace.split('').join(delimiter) + "(With option)";
                    }
            } else {
                return content;
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: let me get it straight. you're removing all instances of spaces where there's one or more spaces in the string, and then splitting them where there is no space?

Comment: check this [answer on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650656/angularjs-access-scope-from-controller-in-custom-filter) i believe it'll be useful.

Comment: Actually, I need to separate a string in Input field with a delimiter in delimiter field. for example, in default, Input field is : "Angular is awesome", if the delimiter is "#“ I need to turn it to： ”A#n#g#u#l#a#r#i#s#a#w#e#s#o#m#e“

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/kXQGTj1sABKOuxObOhn7?p=preview.

Default isn't needed, just check if delimiter is present

```
filter("tokenize", function () {
return function (content, delimiter) {
        if (angular.isString(content)) {
            return content
                      .replace(/ +/g, "")
                      .split('')
                      .join(delimiter || ',');
        } else {
            return content;
        }
    };
})
```

And the use

```
<p>{{delimiter}}</p>
<p>{{greeting | tokenize}}</p>
<p>{{greeting | tokenize:delimiter}}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you Silvinus, that's what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,  its working    http://plnkr.co/edit/VFOEADpoWRq0E43GTXpn?p=preview

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Tokenizer Filter</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <script src="filter.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TokenizeControler">
        <p>Input: <input ng-model="greeting" /></p>
        <p>Delimiter: <input id="delimiter" ng-model="delimiter" /></p>
        <p>{{delimiter}}</p>
        <p>{{greeting | tokenize: defualt}}</p>
        <p>{{greeting | tokenize:false:delimiter}}</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

controller.js

```
var myApp = angular
    .module("myApp", [])
    .controller("TokenizeControler",
        function($scope) {
            $scope.greeting = "Angular is awesome";
            $scope.delimiter = "#";
            $scope.defualt = true;
        });
```

filter.js

```
myApp.filter("tokenize", function() {
    return function(content, defualt, delim) {
        if (angular.isString(content)) {
            var noSpace, output;
            noSpace = content.replace(/ +/g, "");
            if (defualt) {
                return output = noSpace.split('').join(',') + " (Default)";
            } else {
                delimiter = delim; //document.getElementById('delimiter').value;
                return output = noSpace.split('').join(delimiter) + "(With option)";
            }
        } else {
            return content;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you Rejs, that's exactly what I needed. Can I ask: in  <p>{{greeting | tokenize:false:delimiter}}</p> ,  what is the false mean?

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

check this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/10pKXUSYt7FVnNzI5HSf?p=preview) i think this is what you need, right?

```
myApp.filter("tokenize", function () {
    return function (content, delimiter) {
            if (angular.isString(content)) {
                var noSpace, output;
                noSpace = content.replace(/ +/g, "");
                if (delimiter) {
                    return output = noSpace.split('').join(delimiter) + " (Default)";
                } else {
                    delimiter =  "#";

                    return output = noSpace.split('').join(delimiter) + "(With option)";
                    }
            } else {
                return content;
            }
        };
    });
```

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Tokenizer Filter</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
    <script src="filter.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="TokenizeControler">
        <p>Input: <input ng-model="greeting" /></p>
        <p>Delimiter: <input id="delimiter"  ng-model="delimiter" /></p>
        <p>{{delimiter}}</p>
        <p>{{greeting | tokenize}}</p>
        <p>{{greeting | tokenize: delimiter}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```