# How to access scope variables from within a directive in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, scope

I have defined my own custom filter, in order to search through posts in an angular.js web application:

```
app.filter('myfilter', function() {
return function(postList, term) {
  var out = [];

  if(!postList) return out;    
  if(!term) return postList;

  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < postList.length; i++){
    if(postList[i].title.indexOf(term) >=0){
        out.push(postList[i]);
    }

    if($scope.isContentFilterOn.checked){
        if(postList[i].text.indexOf(term) >=0){
                out.push(postList[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    }
    return out;
}
});
```

Of course the above will not work, because I can't access scope variables, and simply passing the `$scope` doesn't work as well. How could I do it - is there any simple and fast way?

Edit: source http://plnkr.co/edit/G9BFBTaKdUmki8MJegrn?p=catalogue

Comment: possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596246/access-scope-variables-from-a-filter-in-angularjs

Comment: This is what services were made for. Create an api to hold the state of the filter and let the controller and directive use them both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass any number of scope members directly to the filter (separated by a colon)...

```
myfilter:filterTerm:isContentFilterOn
```

Update the filter method signature...

```
function(postList, term, isContentFilterOn) {
```

Then use it how you wish...

```
 if (isContentFilterOn) {
```

Oh and don't forget you may need to define isContentFilterOn in the scope as false to begin with so it's available to the filter right away...

```
$scope.isContentFilterOn = false;
```

Updated Plunker here to show what I mean...

http://plnkr.co/edit/vPTBws0JBpwvKY0ywCPC?p=preview

Comment: Also fyi you don't use **isContentFilterOn.checked** just **isContentFilterOn** (as the ng-model will resolve to true or false because a checkbox element can only have 2 values (checked/unchecked i.e. true/false).