# Array.prototype.filter() argument with arrow function callback? (no this binding)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Inspired by [this article](https://hackernoon.com/rethinking-javascript-death-of-the-for-loop-c431564c84a8), I've been refactoring some old code.

However, I'm running into problems with passing arguments using `Array.prototype.filter` since the second parameter of `Array.prototype.filter(callback, thisArg)` binds the `this`-object in the callback but arrow functions don’t bind `this`.

In my example, I’m getting the keys from an associative array (yeah I know, technically not available in JavaScript) by using `Object.keys()`, then filtering that array by a property of their object in the associative array `this[item].property`, but that fails since this binding isn’t available.

So, embracing arrow functions, how does one pass parameters to the callback in `filter()`?

```js
const arr = {
    a: {
      property: true,
      otherProp: false
    },
    b: {
      property: true,
      otherProp: false
    },
  },
  hasProperty = item => this[item].property,
  getMatchingKeys = object => Object.keys(object).filter(hasProperty, object);
getMatchingKeys(arr);
```

Comment: arrow function dont bind to this on there own https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Why does it need to involve `this` in the first place? `.filter(v => arr[v].property)` extremely readable and short already.

Comment: Are `hasProperty` and `getMatchingKeys` really supposed to be inside the `arr` object literal?

Comment: Don't use an arrow function if you need `this` to be the method context.

Comment: "*So, embracing arrow functions*" - that's clearly the wrong attitude. One should only use arrows where they are useful, and one should not try to use them where they don't work.

Comment: @Bergi Hmm I'm not sure you've grasped the question. The task at hand is not finding out whether or not arrow functions should be used but plainly a coding exercise, can they be used in this fashion? Similarly I don't agree with the tagging of this question as a dupe, the question clearly states an understanding that this-binding isn't available (thus knowing they're not interchangeable) and it's not asking if it this is recommended practice but rather, if one were to adhere to this style of coding, how would one do it

Comment: @Bergi the solution to this proved to be currying a function, see solution here https://medium.com/@joelthoms/okay-i-see-what-you-are-trying-to-do-you-are-very-close-b09619da9184?source=linkShare-160f62d1b3c4-1504246051 I strongly disagree with closing this issue without providing a solution

Comment: @Hessius I think loganfsmyth already provided a good solution. Of course you can always use higher order functions to abstract out a value.

Comment: @bergi Obviously several solutions applicable, none of those provided by the questions you provided as duplicates though?

Comment: @Hessius Maybe you're right, they're the wrong targets. (Originally I even pointed to [Methods in ES6 objects: using arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095710/methods-in-es6-objects-using-arrow-functions) as I thought the arrow function was part of the object literal). How about [pass more parameters into callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/939032/1048572) or [How do I pass an extra parameter to the callback function in Javascript .filter() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7759237/1048572) instead?

Comment: @Bergi Yes! Those are actually helpful. Posted an answer with the solution I went with along with your links (to help visibility, as most people don't bother with long comment threads). Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries`. It provides both the key and the value, so that you don't need the reference to the object itself:

```js
const arr = {
        a: {
            property: true,
            otherProp: false
        },
        b: {
            property: true,
            otherProp: false
        },
        c: {
            property: false, // to be excluded
            otherProp: true
        },
    },
    hasProperty = ([key, value]) => value.property,
    first = ([key]) => key,
    getMatchingKeys = object => Object.entries(object).filter(hasProperty).map(first);

console.log(getMatchingKeys(arr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could also use `bind` -- not to bind `this`, but a first argument:

```js
const arr = {
        a: {
            property: true,
            otherProp: false
        },
        b: {
            property: true,
            otherProp: false
        },
        c: {
            property: false, // to be excluded
            otherProp: true
        },
    },
    hasProperty = (object, key) => object[key].property,
    getMatchingKeys = object => Object.keys(object).filter(hasProperty.bind(null, arr));

console.log(getMatchingKeys(arr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

See also some other options in [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37616104/5459839).

Comment: I couldn’t get this to work? For me it produces the same array as using keys?

Comment: It does not produce the same for me. I added a `c` property which has `property: false`: the output will only have `a` and `b`, because only those have `property: true`. Is this not what you wanted as output? Can you then edit your question and specify what the desired output is?

Comment: Thank you, this updated snippet does indeed produce a different result, the filtering is correct but the returned array unfortunately is not, this returns an array of the objects, without the keys whereas the wanted result is an array of the keys.

Comment: I adapted the answer to that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the article provided an [answer in the comments](https://medium.com/@joelthoms/okay-i-see-what-you-are-trying-to-do-you-are-very-close-b09619da9184), provided here for reference:

```
const arr = {
  a: {
    property: true,
    otherProp: false,
  },
  b: {
    property: true,
    otherProp: false,
  },
}
const hasProperty = object => item => object[item].property
const getMatchingKeys = object => Object.keys(object).filter(hasProperty(arr))
getMatchingKeys(arr) // = ['a', 'b']
```

Further reading, provided by @bergi in comments of original post (buried deep, posted here for greater visibility):

1. [jQuery pass more parameters into callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/939032/1048572)
2. [How do I pass an extra parameter to the callback function in Javascript .filter() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7759237/1048572)