# Passing a variable to filter callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

When passing a callback to filter. value, index and Array object is passed to the callback parameters, so how is it possible for me to create a reusable filter callback where i can pass any animal type and filter accordingly.

I did look at [How do I pass an extra parameter to the callback function in Javascript .filter() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759237/how-do-i-pass-an-extra-parameter-to-the-callback-function-in-javascript-filter/27255520#27255520)
but could not get it to work as intended

```
let animals = [
  { name: "fiddo", type: "dog" },
  { name: "garfield", type: "cat" },
  { name: "diddi", type: "bird" },
  { name: "bob", type: "cat" },
];
```

This is what i want to do, I know it is not possible, but how could i achive something "similar"?

```
function filterAnyAnimal(animal, index, arr, typeVariable) {
  if (animal.type === typeVariable) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(animals.filter(filterAnyAnimal));
```

do i really have to do like this? or is there a way to pass a variable?

```
function isDog(animal) {
  if (animal.type === "dog") {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You can do what the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7759286/218196) of the question you linked to suggests: Make `filterAnyAnimal` accept `typeVariable` as parameter and let it *return* a filter function. Then use it as `animals.filter(filterAnyAnimal('dog'))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [felix-kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) comment said and his already [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759237/how-do-i-pass-an-extra-parameter-to-the-callback-function-in-javascript-filter/27255520#27255520), you could do:

```js
let animals = [
  { name: "fiddo", type: "dog" },
  { name: "garfield", type: "cat" },
  { name: "diddi", type: "bird" },
  { name: "bob", type: "cat" },
];
function filterAnyAnimal(typeVariable, animalType) {
   if (animalType === typeVariable) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
let wordToFilter = 'cat';
console.log(animals.filter(function(element){
    return filterAnyAnimal(element.type, wordToFilter);
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let animals = [
  { name: "fiddo", type: "dog" },
  { name: "garfield", type: "cat" },
  { name: "diddi", type: "bird" },
  { name: "bob", type: "cat" },
];

const result = animals.map(animal=>animal.type==="dog"?true:false);

console.log(result);
```

Map function can give you the desired result